Instagram API endpoint to get ANY post details. In large scale
Looking for actual Instagram API endpoint (maybe private API) to get post details by post_id/short_code/media_id. I want to send many of requests hourly. Preferably without athentification.
Was using https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=2b0673e0dc4580674a88d426fe00ea90&variables=%7B%22shortcode%22%3A%22C3-3zvhNA_g%22%7D - but it requires sessionid auth cookie and hit rate-limits pretty fast.
Found this on internet, but it does not seem to work anymore:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media_id}/info?access_token={access_token}

Adding ?__a=1&__d=dis at the end of the post also requires sessionid.
https://www.instagram.com/p/C8q-Lg4tCEC/?__a=1&__d=dis

